# PhantomJS skip header on first page

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I want to remove header from first page and I have header defined as:

```
header = {
    height: header_height,
    contents: phantom.callback(function(pageNum, numPages) {
        if(pageNum == 1) {
            return "";
        }
        return header_contents;
    })
};
```

But it lefts empty margin with `header_height`. Are there any way to set `header.height=0` for first page?

Comment: I'm researching this and it seems it can't be done unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set margin specifically for the first page. But you can include css style on the first page as phantomjs respects css margin